# Reactive Extensions .MaxBy

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Why does

```
var a = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .Publish();

a.Subscribe(o =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test");
});
a.Connect();
```

fire, but not

```
var a = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .MaxBy(o=>o)
    .Publish();

a.Subscribe(o =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test");
});
a.Connect();
```

I am trying to use MaxBy in a different scenario but can't even get the above to work.

This is my more complex example

```
var _telemetryBatchObservable = Observable.FromEventPattern<DeviceStateStreamEventArg>(
        ev => DeviceStateStreamEvent += ev,
        ev => DeviceStateStreamEvent -= ev)
    .Synchronize()
    .GroupBy(o => o.EventArgs.DeviceId)
    .Select(o => o.MaxBy(i => i.EventArgs.DateTimeOffset))
    .SelectMany(o => o.Select(i => i))
    .SelectMany(o => o.Select(i => i))
    .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000), 100)
    .Publish();
```

Answer (score 4):

`Max` and `MaxBy` only emit a single value, when the source observable is terminated. If you have a non-terminating source, they'll never emit.

Try this code as a counter-example:

```
var a = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .Take(3) //causes termination after 3 values
    .MaxBy(o => o)
    .Publish();
```

Comment: How is one suppose to know what will work for non-terminating sources and what not?

Comment: Documentation, experimentation. Almost all of the aggregation operators only emit on termination: The only exception is Scan. Rx is patterned after Linq, which also only emits a single value upon enumerable completion.

Comment: Buffer and Sample works fine with live streams... I could not find any documentation that said MaxBy was not supposed to be used with non - terminating sources.

Comment: There's are the two best documentation sites, both describe it accurately: http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/07_Aggregation.html#MaxAndMin http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/max.html

Comment: If you think there's a lack of documentation, feel free to fill the gap.

Comment: @Murdock - It shouldn't be too hard to imagine that an operator that returns a maximum value can only do so when the sequence terminates. Otherwise how does it know when to return a value? If there's always the possibility of another value then that value could be the maximum value produced.

Comment: @Shlomo - Just being picky, but `.Take(3)` doesn't `//causes termination after 3 seconds`, which I'm sure you know. Obviously in your code it does because it's after `.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))`, but it might be confusing for beginners. It might be better to say `//causes termination after 3 values`.

Comment: Updated comment

Answer (score 2):

Shlomo's nailed it as `.MaxBy` can't produce a value on a non-terminating sequence.

If you want you can use `.Scan` to create a sequence of the maximum value to date.

You could do this:

```
var a =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .Select(x => x % 4L)
        .Scan(long.MinValue, (x, y) => x > y ? x : y)
        .Publish();

a.Subscribe(o =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(o);
});
a.Connect();
```

I put in the `.Select(x => x % 4L)` to make the sequence more interesting.

That gives:

```
0
1
2
3
3
3
3
3
```

If you want to only produce a value if there is a new maximum then add a `.DistinctUntilChanged()` after the `.Scan`. Nice and simple.